Update multiple columns in Spark SQL
In PostgreSQL, I can set multiple columns to NULL then view the table as follows:
    CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(10),
    age  INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
(1, 'Alice', 20),
(2, 'Bob',   40),
(3, 'X',     NULL),
(4, 'X',     0),
(5,  NULL,   99),
(6,  '',     99);


UPDATE mytable SET 
    name = null,
    age = null;

SELECT * FROM mytable;

This returns a table with the same columns and number of rows as the original table, only every value in the referenced columns within the SET command are set to NULL.
Is there an equivalent way to do this in Spark SQL? The Spark SQL documentation does not appear to point to comparable capability.
Any workarounds to convert an entire column to NULL values within a SELECT statement would be welcome, too.

See this Spark issue you cannot use spark to delete/update a table. Seems this Spark-acid maybe a solution.
